# Parallel Chaining of APA102 LED matrices

Tags: led, arduino-due, rgb-led

I have four APA102 LED matrices (those flexible ones) and I want to connect them together to make a display for showing images. Now my problem is this:

Consider the coordinate system with four quadrants. I put one matrix in each of the quadrant and my target is to have a one single display as mentioned above. I connect like this: The input of matrix 1 is connected to Arduino, the output of matrix 1 to input of matrix 2, output of matrix 2 to input of matrix 3 (or can be input of 4 also ) and then finally output of 3 (or output of 4th matrix) is connected to input of 4th matrix (or input of 3rd matrix accordingly).

The problem with this is that although this might seem a big display from a distance with 4 matrices working in sync but actually its 4 matrices daisy chained and split into 2 rows. This would split my image if I were to display.

Question: Is it possible to parallel chain these APA102 matrices and thereby form one continuous display which can be controlled by FASTLED library?? I might be somehow able to address an individual LED in this type of weird pattern, but while displaying images, I am lost. Can't figure out how to do that? Realised that I need to have parallel chaining.....which I have no idea of.

Any help, guidance would be great!

Thanks

Comment: It's a problem that can easily be fixed in software. Some libraries support this kind of paneling out of the box.

Comment: @Gerben Thanks bro! I managed to do a very simple yet effective solution: I split the bitmap data depending on the total number of columns of those flexible matrix (continuous serpentine):P ...

Comment: How about write up an answer and share it with us?